# Multiple if and else statements

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make some plots using matplotlib in python.

I then have a loop going through:

```
structure = ['CTV', 'ITV', 'PTV', 'Index']
```

Now, some stuff is going on in the loop (`for voi in structure`) like getting data from .txt-files, subplots and formatting the plots, and then I arrive at my axis formatting. For each structure there will be some different axis dimensions, which are not achieved automatically by matplotlib.
So what I wanted to do was the following:

```
plt.axis([0, 180, 75 if voi=='PTV' else 92 if voi=='CTV' else 15 if voi=='ITV' else 0 if voi=='Index', 82 if voi=='PTV' else 97 if voi=='CTV' else 60 if voi=='ITV' else 40 if voi=='Index'])
```

I know this looks terrible, and it also does not work. But I think you get the point. For each structure, different axis dimensions are needed. And if I only use:

```
75 if voi=='PTV' else 92
```

as an example, it works. But using multiple else statements, well, then it does not. So how would I go about this the easiest way? The one I wrote might look bad, but it's easy to write. But as stated, it does not work like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
poss_voi = {'Index':40,'PTV':75,'ITV':15, 'CTV': 92 etc....}
```

Then just get do a lookup:

```
plt.axis([0, 180, poss_voi[voi]])
```

If you want a default use *dict.get*:

```
 plt.axis([0, 180, poss_voi.get(voi, some_default_value)])
```